# What the difference between different group and aggregate operation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I want to use udaf in pandas because there is no nunique function, but I found it cost too much time. So I test different aggregate method on existing function, and found there is big difference between different method as show below"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

recordNum = 10
n = 2
varNum = 1000
keys = ['ID%04d' %i for i in range(int(recordNum/n))] * n
varlst1 = ['x%04d' %i for i in range(varNum)]

dsDict1 = {k:np.random.choice(range(1000), recordNum) for k in varlst1}

dsDict1['ID'] = keys

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dsDict1)

dfg = df1.groupby(['ID'])

# 1.47ms
%timeit dfg.sum()

# 1.48ms
%timeit dfg.aggregate(sum)

# 1.5s
%timeit dfg.aggregate(pd.Series.sum)

# 361ms
%timeit dfg.aggregate({}.fromkeys(varlst1, sum))
```

Comment: `sum`  is one of the cython optimized aggregation functions. Normally, `np.sum`, `sum`, `'sum'` and `.sum()`  calls that function but apparently pd.Series.sum is not one of them. In general the safe way is to use their aliases (`'sum'` , `'mean'`, `'std'`, `'size'` etc.)